# bash_profile: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

**I get this on my prompt:**

```
-bash: source/Users/sean/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/sean/.bash_profile: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: /Users/sean/.bash_profile: line 3: `PS1=\w >'
Seans-MacBook-Pro:~ sean$ source .bash_profile
-bash: source/Users/sean/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
-bash: .bash_profile: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: .bash_profile: line 3: `PS1=\w >
```

**When I open the .bash_profile this is what it says**

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source/Users/seanlanning/.bash_profile "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
PS1=\w >
PS1='\w >'
```

**Not sure what I messed up and what the .bash_profile should like like**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source/Users/seanlanning/.bash_profile "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

you need a space between `source` and `/Users...`

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you dont have the lines combined:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin`

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function`

**What operating system**?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source/Users/seanlanning/.bash_profile "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

should be

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```